# How to hide the react.js source code in Vite environment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, vite

I am just thinking that how to not generate sourcemap in react.js using vite build. We can do it in create-react-app but how should we do it here ?
webpack makes less Js files (don't know in detail) and make it almost unreadable.
Is there any way to do it in Vite  ?

Answer (score 1):

[Specify `build.sourcemap`](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options#build-sourcemap).

Note that your production build shouldn't get sourcemaps by default anyway; if you're only looking at the output in development mode, that doesn't really matter.